# How do I reuse code in Linux Bison (Yacc)?

Tags: bison, yacc

Here is a snippet of my yacc file:

```
statement:
    expression {
      // code 1
    }
  |
    ROUND_BRACKET_L expression ROUND_BRACKET_R {
      // code 2
    }
;
```

The 'statement' production corresponds to two parsing rules, I wrote C code with exactly the same logic at 'code 1' and 'code 2', this way of writing the same code twice is not good, is there a way to write the code only once and then reuse them?

Answer (score 0):

Put the common code in a function and call that function from both places?